# Mediator actions in F#

Tags: f#

I have a problem I am tring to create some sort of mediator based on singelton in f#. Main reason for it is I need to register some action in one part of my application and execute it in another similar to c# that looks like:

```
public class Mediator
{
    private static readonly object syncRoot = new object();
    private static Mediator instance;

    public static Mediator Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new Mediator();
                    }
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    public event Action<string> InputLogUpdate;
    public void InvokeInputLogUpdate(string msg)
    {
        InputLogUpdate?.Invoke(msg);
    }
}
```

Invoke looks like:

```
Mediator.Instance.InvokeInputLogUpdate(msg);
```

Register looks like:

```
Mediator.Instance.InputLogUpdate += msg => this.DebugSection += $"{msg} \n";
```

But as for now no luck, all I have got is:

```
vnamespace Operation.Mediator

module Mediator = 
open System
type UdpMediator private () =

    static let instance = UdpMediator()
    let mutable UpdateDebigLog : Action<string> = null

    static member Instance = instance
    member this.InvokeUpdateLog (msg:string) = UpdateDebigLog.Invoke(msg)
```

And it does not work very well, any one know how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**First**, that pattern of a `lock` sandwiched between two `null` checks is so antiquated, I don't even remember the last time I saw one. The modern .NET has `Lazy<T>` for such on-demand initialization. And, as luck would have it, F# actually has special syntax for it:

```
type UpdMediator private () =
    
    static member val private _instance = lazy UpdMediator()
    static member Instance = UpdMediator._instance.Value
```

**Second**, an `event Action<_>` in C# is *not* equivalent to `mutable Action<_>` in F#. An `event` declaration in C# actually creates two accessor methods - `add` and `remove`, - just like `get` and `set` with properties.

However, F# actually has a better mechanism - `Event<_>`. You make an instance of that type private, and then expose it via its `.Publish` property, which has type `IEvent<_>`. The consumers can use that `IEvent` value to add and remove handlers, or to subscribe to the events observable-style (because `IEvent` inherits from `IObservable`):

```
type UpdMediator private () =
    ...

    member val private _updDebugLog = Event<string>()
    member this.UpdDebugLog = this._updDebugLog.Publish

    member this.InvokeUpdDebugLog() = this._updDebugLog.Trigger "foo"


// usage:
UpdMediator.Instance.UpdDebugLog.AddHandler (fun sender str -> printfn "%s" str)

// Or observable-style:
UpdMediator.Instance.UpdDebugLog.Subscribe (printfn "%s")
```

(note that `.Subscribe` returns an `IDisposable`, which can be used later to cancel the subscription)

**Third**, attempting to translate C# practices into F# word for word usually does not end well. F# usually has better facilities than C#, so a word-for-word translation usually ends up kinda awkward, as your case illustrates.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to use C#, OOP-style design patterns in F# usually results in WAY overcomplicating things compared to the natural way of expressing things in idiomatic F#. What you have said you need is a way to have one part of your code register an action, and another part of your code execute the registered action if it has been registered. Since you're using events, I assume you want to be able to register multiple actions and have all of them fire. So here's some code that would do just that:

```
module ActionRegistry

let mutable private actions : (string -> unit) list = []

let register f =
    actions <- f :: actions

let invokeRegisteredActions() =
    actions
    |> List.iter (fun action -> action())
```

Now isn't that a LOT simpler to understand than a singleton Mediator class? OOP-style design patterns always overcomplicate things.

P.S. You haven't mentioned unregistering actions, so I left the design simple and didn't include an unregistration function. If you do need to unregister actions, I'd do something like keep a list of (int, action) pairs, with a simple incrementing counter ensuring that the int part of the pair keeps going up. Then the register function would return an int, and the unregister function would take an int and filter out the pair with that int in the first position.

Comment: Note that this would fire events in the opposite order they were registered, e.g. in LIFO order. If you need FIFO order, then change `f :: actions` to `List.append actions [f]`. That's an O(N) operation rather than O(1), so your overall operation would be O(N^2). But I doubt you'll be registering more than a few actions, so with low N the difference between O(N) and O(N^2) really doesn't matter.

Comment: Good point; the OP used locks. If thread safety is required, a System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue or System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentStack would be better than a plain list.

Comment: Or use a single `MailboxProcessor` inside the module to manage the state and invoke the actions in-order.